# Extract static methods from main() file in java

Tags: java, methods, static, extract

I'm quite new to Java and wrote a little to-do list project.
At the beginning of the project I added a bunch of static methods to the file where my main() code is, and it got a little out of hand. I want to transfer these methods to another file.
Is there a proper way to do this, or do I just have to create some sort of Behaviour class for these methods, and then in main() create an instance of it to call it's methods?

Comment: simply copy all your methods in a new java class file, and replace their calls by <newClassName>.staticMethodName...

Comment: With IDEs you can refactor your code. Most offer something like "Move... -> Method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract these methods to a separate class (say `FooUtils`), and then in your main method you can call them using the class name - `FooUtils.someStaticMethod()`

Depending on what you have, it may make sense to group your methods into different classes, or to make them instance methods.